# Grab post back collection and show it on list over webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC webpage with a `DropDownList` full of items.
Every item is an object from my `Database` that represent a file on disk.

My object class:

```
namespace CapturesMVC.Models

public class Capture : IEquatable<Capture>
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "File Name")]
    public string fileName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Browser")]
    public string browser { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Mobile")]
    public string mobile { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Protocol")]
    public string protocol_site { get; set; }

    public string family { get; set; }

    public sealed override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return Equals(other as Capture);
    }

    public bool Equals(Capture other)
    {
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.protocol_site == other.protocol_site;
        }
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return protocol_site.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

CaptureDBContext class:

```
namespace CapturesMVC.Models

public class CaptureDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Capture> Captures { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string File)
{
    var list = db.Captures.Where(x => x.protocol== File).ToArray();
    ViewBag.Files = list;
    return View();
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    <div>   
        @Html.DropDownList("File", new SelectList(ViewBag.Files, "protocol_site", "protocol_site"), "Select webmail site", new { style = "vertical-align:middle;" })
        <button type="submit">Select</button>
    </div>
}
</body>
```

After choosing an item from my `DropDownList` and hitting the button, the `Index` action is executed and returns list of objects that match one of my object properties and this list I want to show over my webpage inside a list, but the current situation is that this list is inserted into my `DropDownList`.

Comment: What do you mean by "this list i want to show over my webpage inside list"?

Comment: i want to show all this objects inside list, for example listView, something with columns

Answer (score 0):

You want to implement Cascading DropDownList

[check this example 'Cascading DropDownList in ASP.Net MVC' on msdn code](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Cascading-DropDownList-in-833683f9/sourcecode?fileId=48387&pathId=451527572) or [this on c-sharpcorner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/dropdown-cascading-in-mvc4-using-entity-framework/)

Comment: I don't want Cascading, i want list with columns in oder ot show all my opject's properties inside and a link -> download to download this file (one of the properties is fileName that represent the whole file path)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you put the objects in the same `ViewBag` property that your Dropdownlist gets its values from.

You could make a `List` and put that in your `ViewBag`:

```
List<Capture> list = db.Captures.Where(x => x.protocol== File).ToList();
ViewBag.data = list;
```

And enumerate over these and display some html in your view (within an unordered list for example). But you have to cast it back to a list first:

```
@using Namespace.Capture
...
<ul>
foreach (var item in (ViewBag.data as List<Capture>))
{
    <li>@item.Property</li>
}
</ul>
```

ViewBag is a C# 4 dynamic type. You need to cast the entities from it to use them in a type-safe way.

But I would recommend using a view model with the list as a property and sending that to the view from your controller action.

Comment: Where this foreach should placed ? i can see that if this foreach is inside my <div></div> --> unknown element Capture or element cannot placed here

Comment: You need to ad a using statement in your view, like I've added to the example, so that the compiler recognizes your `Capture` type. You do have an entity that's called `Capture`, right? I assumed your `db.Captures` would consist of these.

Comment: I added my namespace and still nor recognized, db.Captures is my entity yes

Comment: Could you post the code of your `Captures` class and your `DbContext` class? (including namespaces).

Comment: @user2976270 So if you add `@using CapturesMVC.Models.Capture` in the top of your view, it doesn't recognize it?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't recognize it